# How to compile / link / build a small sized Loadable Kernel Module ( LKM )?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I successfully built this trivial LKM with *`gcc`* but the resulting binary is of size 70kB.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init LinuxKernelModule_init(void)
{
    printk("LinuxKernelModule: Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit LinuxKernelModule_exit(void)
{
    printk("LinuxKernelModule: Goodbye, world!\n");
}

module_init(LinuxKernelModule_init);
module_exit(LinuxKernelModule_exit);
```

What CFLAGS and *`make`* arguments would you suggest to make it smaller?

Comment: Why do you care what size it is?

Comment: How did you compile it - with what options? Show us your Makefile. I compiled this example also and it is 4152 bytes long.

Comment: Get rid of the printk calls and it gets smaller

Comment: @ user2699113 There are so many options passed to `gcc` and `ld` that they would not fit here. Can you post an answer listing your minimal `gcc` options that yielded the the 4152 byte long file ?  This would tell me what options to avoid and which are superfluous.

Comment: I just compiled the example with the simplest makefile that doesn't add any compiler or linked options. The resulting module is 3896 bytes long. `gcc` version is 7.4.0, `ldd` version is 2.27, kernel is 4.15.0-66-generic, the distro is Ubuntu.
```
KERNEL = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build


obj-m += lkm.o

all:
        ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL} M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL} M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: @Aleksey OK, make it an answer and I will accept it for posterity.

Comment: `make ... INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install` will shrink it. It's independent to the distro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Linux kernel is compiled in an optimal way already unless it's a debug version or some very specific options are turned on. So the simplest Makefile for an external kernel module which doesn't add any compiler of linker options on top of those used to build the kernel should be sufficient and should produce an optimal kernel module.

For this trivial LKM (let's call it `lkm.c`) the simplest Makefile below produces a kernel module that is 3986 bytes in size on my system. `gcc` version is `7.4.0`, `ldd` version is `2.27`, the kernel is `4.15.0-66-generic`, the distro is Ubuntu.

```
KERNEL = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

obj-m += lkm.o

all:
        ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL} M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL} M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: And on my machine it doesn't. See my comment to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just make Makefile with following contents:

```
obj-m += test.o
```

and rename your module to test.c in the same directory.

Then make the module:

```
 make -C /usr/src/linux M=`pwd`
```

and tell us what is the size of your output .ko file.

It is also possible that your .config of the kernel has enabled debugging symbols and it increases size of your module.

Comment: I accepted Alexey's answer because I promised him that verbatum in the comments

Comment: Same comment as to @Aleksey answer.

Comment: @0andriy: Yes, and that is why I was writing about debugging symbols in kernel module.